Issues with training Unet model using .tif data
I'm currently working on training a Unet model to segment images using GIS data, thus it is saved as a .tif file. Rasterio has been my latest approach to importing the data, but the output of the trained model seems to not be consistent.
I have tried different iterations of my customgeo dataset class to little effect. The images are being read, but I'm concerned my approach to converting to tensors for training is not the right approach for the model. Furthermore, I am only using a 3-band image to train, but would like to ultimately transition to using 8-band images.
Another issue suspect is the mask not being of the quality required for training, leading to the output varying afte training at different points.
I would love some input on this situation as to how I can create a better model.
import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, RandomSampler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define paths to local .tif files
image_path = "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/BCMCA/bcmca_small_true.tif"
mask_path = "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/BCMCA/bcmca_mask.tif"

class CustomGeoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_path, mask_path, patch_size=256):
        self.image_path = image_path
        self.mask_path = mask_path
        self.patch_size = patch_size

        # Open the images
        self.image_src = rasterio.open(self.image_path)
        self.mask_src = rasterio.open(self.mask_path)
        self.height, self.width = self.image_src.height, self.image_src.width

    def __len__(self):
        # We will define an arbitrary number of samples
        return 1000  # Modify as per your requirement

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        x = np.random.randint(0, self.width - self.patch_size)
        y = np.random.randint(0, self.height - self.patch_size)

        image = self.image_src.read(window=rasterio.windows.Window(x, y, self.patch_size, self.patch_size))
        mask = self.mask_src.read(1, window=rasterio.windows.Window(x, y, self.patch_size, self.patch_size))

        # Convert to torch tensors
        image = torch.from_numpy(image).float()
        mask = torch.from_numpy(mask).long()

        # Normalize the image to range [0, 1] if necessary
        image = image / 255.0

        sample = {"image": image, "mask": mask}
        return sample

# Create dataset instances
train_dataset = CustomGeoDataset(image_path, mask_path)
val_dataset = CustomGeoDataset(image_path, mask_path) 

# Set the ratio for splitting into training and validation sets
train_ratio = 0.8  # 80% for training, 20% for validation
total_samples = 100  # Samples number after augmentation
train_size = int(train_ratio * total_samples)
val_size = total_samples - train_size

# Use RandomSampler to sample regions from the dataset
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_dataset, num_samples=train_size, replacement=True)
val_sampler = RandomSampler(val_dataset, num_samples=val_size, replacement=True)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=16)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, sampler=val_sampler, batch_size=16)

# Let's print a random element of the training dataset
random_element = np.random.randint(0, len(train_loader))
for idx, sample in enumerate(train_loader):
    if idx != random_element:
        continue

    # Let's select the first sample from the batch
    image = sample["image"][0]
    target = sample["mask"][0]

    # Ensure the image has 3 bands (RGB)
    if image.shape[0] == 3:
        # Create a figure and a 1x2 grid of axes
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

        # Plot the first image in the left axis
        # Select only first 3 bands and cast to uint8
        rgb_image = np.transpose(image.numpy().squeeze(), (1, 2, 0))
        axes[0].imshow((rgb_image * 255).astype('uint8'))
        axes[0].set_title('RGB image')

        # Plot the labels image in the right axis
        target_image = target.numpy().squeeze()
        axes[1].imshow(target_image, cmap='gray')
        axes[1].set_title('Mask')

        # Adjust layout to prevent clipping of titles
        plt.tight_layout()

        # Show the plots
        plt.show()
    else:
        print("Image does not have 3 bands.")


print(f"RGB Image min: {rgb_image.min()}, max: {rgb_image.max()}")

class DoubleConv(nn.Module):
    """(convolution => [BN] => ReLU) * 2"""
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, mid_channels=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not mid_channels:
            mid_channels = out_channels
        self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, mid_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(mid_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(mid_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.double_conv(x)

class Down(nn.Module):
    """Downscaling with maxpool then double conv"""
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool_conv(x)

class Up(nn.Module):
    """Upscaling then double conv"""
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, bilinear=True):
        super().__init__()
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels, in_channels // 2)
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)

    def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.up(x1)
        diffY = x2.size()[2] - x1.size()[2]
        diffX = x2.size()[3] - x1.size()[3]
        x1 = F.pad(x1, [diffX // 2, diffX - diffX // 2,
                        diffY // 2, diffY - diffY // 2])
        x = torch.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
        return self.conv(x)

class OutConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(OutConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)

class UNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels, n_classes, bilinear=True):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.bilinear = bilinear

        self.inc = DoubleConv(n_channels, 64)
        self.down1 = Down(64, 128)
        self.down2 = Down(128, 256)
        self.down3 = Down(256, 512)
        factor = 2 if bilinear else 1
        self.down4 = Down(512, 1024 // factor)
        self.up1 = Up(1024, 512 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up2 = Up(512, 256 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up3 = Up(256, 128 // factor, bilinear)
        self.up4 = Up(128, 64, bilinear)
        self.outc = OutConv(64, n_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.inc(x)
        x2 = self.down1(x1)
        x3 = self.down2(x2)
        x4 = self.down3(x3)
        x5 = self.down4(x4)
        x = self.up1(x5, x4)
        x = self.up2(x, x3)
        x = self.up3(x, x2)
        x = self.up4(x, x1)
        logits = self.outc(x)
        return logits

from tqdm import tqdm

# Define necessary variables
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
nb_channels = 3  # Number of input channels (RGB)
nb_classes = 1  # Number of output classes (binary mask)

# Initialize model, loss function, and optimizer
model = UNet(n_channels=nb_channels, n_classes=nb_classes).to(device)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 10
log_dict = {'loss_per_batch': [], 'loss_per_epoch': []}
best_loss = float('inf')

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for batch in tqdm(train_loader):
        inputs = batch["image"][:, 0:3, :, :] / 255.0  # Normalize inputs to [0, 1]
        targets = batch["mask"].unsqueeze(1)  # Add a channel dimension

        # Move data to device
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets.float())  # BCEWithLogitsLoss does not require sigmoid

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        log_dict['loss_per_batch'].append(loss.item())

    # Evaluation phase
    model.eval()
    total_val_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for val_batch in val_loader:
            val_inputs = val_batch["image"][:, 0:3, :, :] / 255.0  # Normalize inputs to [0, 1]
            val_targets = val_batch["mask"].unsqueeze(1)  # Add a channel dimension

            # Move data to device
            val_inputs = val_inputs.to(device)
            val_targets = val_targets.to(device)

            val_outputs = model(val_inputs)
            val_loss = criterion(val_outputs, val_targets.float())
            total_val_loss += val_loss.item()

    # Calculate the average loss
    average_val_loss = total_val_loss / len(val_loader)
    log_dict['loss_per_epoch'].append(average_val_loss)

    # Check if current performance is better than the best so far
    if average_val_loss < best_loss:
        best_loss = average_val_loss
        # Save the model checkpoint
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model.pt')

    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Training Loss: {running_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)}, Validation Loss: {average_val_loss}")

mport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Initialize lists to store metrics for averaging later
all_losses = []

# Iterate over batches or samples in the validation loader
for batch in val_loader:
    # Extract batch of images and masks
    inputs = batch["image"][:, 0:3, :, :]  # Select only first 3 channels
    targets = batch["mask"]

    # Move data to device
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    targets = targets.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)

        # Calculate loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets.unsqueeze(1).float())

        # Convert logits to predicted class labels (assuming binary classification)
        predicted_masks = torch.sigmoid(outputs)

        # Convert tensors to numpy arrays for visualization and metrics
        image_np = inputs.cpu().squeeze().numpy()  # Remove batch dimension and move to CPU
        target_np = targets.cpu().squeeze().numpy()
        predicted_mask_np = predicted_masks.cpu().squeeze().numpy()

        # Calculate and store loss
        all_losses.append(loss.item())

        # Optionally, print or use the calculated metrics
        print("Loss on current batch:", loss.item())

        # Iterate over the batch to plot each image and its masks
        for idx in range(len(image_np)):
            # Create a figure and a 1x3 grid of axes
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))

            # Plot the original image
            axes[0].imshow(image_np[idx].transpose((1, 2, 0)))  # Transpose to (H, W, C) for plotting
            axes[0].set_title('Original Image')

            # Plot the ground truth mask (grayscale)
            axes[1].imshow(target_np[idx], cmap='gray')
            axes[1].set_title('Ground Truth Mask')

            # Plot the predicted mask (grayscale)
            axes[2].imshow(predicted_mask_np[idx], cmap='gray')
            axes[2].set_title('Predicted Mask')

            # Adjust layout to prevent clipping of titles
            plt.tight_layout()

            # Show the plots for the current image
            plt.show()

# Calculate average loss over all batches
average_loss = np.mean(all_losses)
print("Average Loss on Validation Set:", average_loss)


It find it difficult to give detailed advice here... but you could have a look here, it might give some inspiration: https://github.com/orthoseg/orthoseg
